# Phoenix - controller with multiple render

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Trying to create an app with Elixir + Phoenix, that would be able to handle both "browser" and "api" requests to handle its resources.

Is it possible to do it without having to do something like that :

```
scope "/", App do
  pipe_through :browser

  resources "/users", UserController
end

scope "/api", App.API as: :api do
  pipe_through :api

  resources "/users", UserController
end
```

which would mean having to create two controllers, which might have the same behavior, except that it will render HTML with the *browser* pipeline and, say JSON, for the *api* pipeline.

I was thinking maybe something like the Rails `respond_to do |format| ...`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it (I would recommend having two controllers and move your logic into a different module that is called by both controllers) but it can be done. You can share a controller, but you still need a separate pipeline to ensure the correct response type (html/json) is set.

The following will use the same controller and view, but render json or html depending on the route. "/" is html, "/api" is json.

Router:

```
defmodule ScopeExample.Router do
  use ScopeExample.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", ScopeExample do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
  end

  scope "/api", ScopeExample do
    pipe_through :api # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
defmodule ScopeExample.PageController do
  use ScopeExample.Web, :controller

  plug :action

  def index(conn, params) do
    render conn, :index
  end
end
```

View:

```
defmodule ScopeExample.PageView do
  use ScopeExample.Web, :view

  def render("index.json", _opts) do
    %{foo: "bar"}
  end
end
```

You can also share the router and have everything served by the same route if you use a router like:

```
defmodule ScopeExample.Router do
  use ScopeExample.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html", "json"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
  end


  scope "/", ScopeExample do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
  end
end
```

You can then specify the format using `?format=json` at the end of the url - I would recommend going with different urls for your API and site however.

Comment: You don't need to interpolate the format, you can use an atom for the template and the accept headers will be used to render the correct format.

Comment: @ChrisMcCord thanks - I tried a couple of things and couldn't get the content-type header working.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @gazler if multiple controllers are the solution, how should we name space them so they are different yet separate? should API controllers go into controllers/API/user_controller.exs ?

Answer (score 31):

As Gazler said, you are probably best served by having separate pipelines, but something like this can be pleasantly done with pattern matching on the same controller actions:

```
def show(conn, %{"format" => "html"} = params) do
  # ...
end

def show(conn, %{"format" => "json"} = params) do
  # ...
end
```

Or if the function bodies are the same, and you would only like to render a template based on the accept headers, you can do:

```
def show(conn, params) do
  # ...

  render conn, :show
end
```

Passing an atom as the template name will cause phoenix to check the accept headers and render the `.json` or `.html` template.

Comment: It doesn't look like the passed in `params` has `format` in it? Has something changed since this answer?

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be valid anymore.  However, you can pattern match like `def index(%{private: %{phoenix_format: "json"}} = conn, params) do`.  I have no idea if this is safe or suggested.

Comment: Instead of getting it directly from `private` (which you should pretty much never do) you should use `get_format(conn)`: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.6.5/Phoenix.Controller.html#get_format/1