# How do I get the request body from a connection?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In the update(conn, params) action of my controller, how do I get out the JSON body passed in by the PUT request?

I see the values as a map in params, but with an "id" inserted into it. And if I pass an "id" it gets overwritten. The original body is probably somewhere in conn, but I don't know how you get to it.

Comment: Can we see your code, sir?

Comment: Do you need it? I just want to know how to access the body of a request from within a controller.

Comment: Not sure if it helps @Matt but take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30625444/2820

Comment: Also this may help too: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/459

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `body_params` on the [Plug.Conn](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html) struct.

e.g.

```
#PUT /users/1
{"user": {"name": "lol"}, "id": 7}
```

- `params["id"]` will be "1"
- `body_params["id"]` will be 7

Hope this works for you.

Since you can only [read_body/2](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#read_body/2) once, accessing the request body is a little more involved. You will need to bypass `Plug.Parsers` in your `Endpoint` for your requests and read the body manually.

From the Plug docs:

> If you need to access the body multiple times, it is your responsibility to store it. Finally keep in mind some plugs like Plug.Parsers may read the body, so the body may be unavailable after accessing such plugs.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: How to match for body_params values in controller action definitions?

Answer (score 7):

If folks come to this when using [`Plug`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug), you're looking to use [`Plug.Parsers`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Parsers.html).

Specifically you can do the following in your router file:

```
  plug Plug.Parsers, parsers: [:json],
                     pass:  ["text/*"],
                     json_decoder: Poison
  plug :match
  plug :dispatch

  # ...

  post "/" do
    IO.puts inspect conn.body_params
  end
```